# KBDcache.dll is taking 32GB - is that normal?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I am using Windows 7 ultimate, 32 bit edition on my Lenovo laptop.

I had partitioned the C drive to be 50GB (I know... I know..) and I cannot re-format it now. I have been getting "Less space on C drive" warnings, and hence decided to clean it up. Here are the steps I have already taken:

- I ran CCleaner (including wiping MFT space), which increased the free space from 1.2 GB to 2.3GB
- Disabled "hibernate"
- Ran SpaceSniffer

It was when I ran SpaceSniffer that I saw that the **"KBDcache.dll" is taking up 32GB**.

A few questions:

- Is a 32GB KBDcache.dll normal?
- What else can I do to clean up my C drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given its name (cache for a keyboard) this is most likely a key logger.

Time to start cleaning:

1. Download the three links below in advance.
2. Reboot your computer into Safe Mode.
3. Run [TDSSkiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363) to get rid of rootkits.
4. Run [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) to get rid of any spyware.
5. Run the best virus scanner you have available.
6. Run [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/anti-virus/combofix) to fix any left behinds and save a log for inspection.
7. Reboot your computer.
8. Post the log to us (using [PasteBin](http://www.pastebin.com)) and tell us whether the file has gone away.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will perform those steps and report back.

Comment: I performed all of the above steps.

Comment: 1. TDSSKiller - no prob
2. MalwareBytes - detected 1 malware. Removed
3. Ran AVG.
Surprised to find "Logger.ABDX". I run automated scans weekly, and it had detected the same 6 months ago. I had "removed the threat", but the computer had hung. After 30-40 mins, I shutoff my computer by pressing the power button for 5 seconds. Scanning again, AVG had not detected the virus again, and so I had thought it had been removed. Apparently not.
Also deleted the "KBDcache.dll". It was only visible in SpaceSniffer, and not in explorer. Had to use safe mode to delete it as it was locked by some process.

Comment: @Samudra: Sounds good so far. See [this site](http://home.mcafee.com/virusinfo/virusprofile.aspx?key=995462) for more information about Logger.ABDX, especially check whether the changes mentioned by Virus Characteristics are no longer present on your system. The removal instructions mention to run `bootrec /fixmbr` from the installation medium, which could fix any tampering with the MBR (which might make this virus return). Note that you can't do any of the other instructions there given that they just scan with McAfee, which is why you need to manually correct the virus characteristics.

Comment: A combination of correcting the MBR, scanning with AVG in Safe Mode  and correcting the characteristics could make sure that you are rid of that virus. Did you see anything noteworthy in the ComboFix log or similar tools like HijackThis (in my opinion limited) or AutoRuns (from SysInternals)?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I dont have any installation disks, so I dont know how to fix the MBR. Seraching for that now.

Also, after all the steps, my system seems to be hanging quite a bit. Yesterday, it was hanging every few minutes, and I would have to hard-shut down. I must have done that at least 8-10 times. This was mostly before deleting the KBDcache.dll file in safe mode, and I think once afterwards. Hasnt happened today though. Will be observing more.

Comment: As soon as I had typed out the prev comment, my computer hung again.

I have run combofix and here are the logs:
http://pastebin.com/5hcRUwDm

Comment: @Samudra: That evidences the recreation of `KBDcache.dll`; could you check if it is back, if it is so then there is still a key logger present on your system. `g:\avg pc tuneup\BoostSpeed.exe` seems like a weird entry to me, given that Boost Speed is not from AVG. In case the `KBDcache.dll` file has returned, you can figure out with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) what process is writing to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3355/discussion-between-samudra-and-tom-wijsman)